# Density of unknown metal

Tags: density

> An empty flask weighs $\pu{115.713 g}$. When filled water at $\pu{20 °C}$ it now weighs $\pu{365.263 g}$. The flask is then emptied and a $\pu{15.000 g}$ sample of unknown metal is added to it. It is then filled with water at $\pu{20 °C}$. The combined mass is $\pu{378.426 g}$. What is the density of the unknown metal? The density of water at $\pu{20 °C}$ is $\pu{0.9982 g/ml}$.

Here is my calculation:

Weight of the water: $\pu{249.552 g}$
The volume occupy by the water: $\pu{249.551 g}$ divide by $\pu{0.9982 g/mL}$ yield $V = \pu{250 mL}$.

Then, I don't know what to do I think I should divide the volume of the water by the mass of the unknown metal but I don't understand why I should to that.

Comment: For future reference: chemistry.se offers to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) for the body of questions, answers, and comments.  Do not use it for the headers of questions, because it is not guaranteed every browser processes this equally well.  It equally provides the `\pu{}` command for numerical results, which keeps units typed upright; and the space between the figure and unit *in input* yields a non-breakable space in the output which mostly is fine (except for the description of angles, and percentage/permille sign in English typography).

Answer (score 5):

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline \text{Parameter} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Relation} & \text{Value} \\
\hline 
\text{Flask mass} & m_0 & &\pu{115.713 g} \\
\text{Flask mass with water} & m_1 & & \pu{365.263 g} \\
\text{Water mass} & m_2 & m_2=m_1 - m_0& \pu{249.55 g} \\
\text{Water density} & \rho_\ce{H2O} & &\pu{0.9982 g cm-3} \\
\text{Flask volume} & V_0 & V_0 = \frac{m_2 }{ \rho_\ce{H2O}} &\pu{250.00 ml} \\
\text{Metal mass} & m_3 & & \pu{15.000 g} \\
\text{Mass of flask+metal+water} & m_4 & & \pu{378.426 g} \\
\text{Mass of water only} & m_5 & m_5 = m_4 - m_0 - m_3& \pu{247.713 g} \\
\text{Volume of water only} & V_1 & V_1 = \frac{m_5 }{ \rho_\ce{H2O}} & \pu{248.160 ml} \\
\text{Volume of metal} & V_2 & V_2 = V_0 - V_1 & \pu{1.840 ml} \\
\text{Density of metal} & \rho_\ce{m} & \rho_\ce{m} = \frac{m_3 }{ V_2} & \pu{8.151 g cm-3} \\
\hline
\end{array}